# Full height side navbar made up of images - how to?

Tags: html, css, image, navbar, sidenav

I'm trying to make a side navbar made up of 7 icon images. I have all of the images wrapped in a div, but I want them to be responsive if the browser window shrinks (height). Here's what I have so far,

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="sidenav">
    <div id="nav1"><img src="img/menu.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav2"><img src="img/icon1.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav3"><img src="img/icon2.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav4"><img src="img/icon3.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav5"><img src="img/icon4.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav6"><img src="img/icon5.png" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav7"><img src="img/icon6.png" alt=""></div>
</div>  

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#nav1 img, #nav2 img, #nav3 img, #nav4 img, #nav5 img, #nav6 img, #nav7 img {
    width: 100px;
}
#sidenav {
    position: fixed;
}
```

So basically, whenever the browser is resized vertically, I want all of the images to resize with it, so that all 7 are always equally visible and square. Later, I want to make these images buttons, but firt I need to figure this out. Thanks in advance for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i actually have accomplished this on my page (super excited to truly answer my first question).

so what did was divided the screen by the number of icons and got a position for each icon. for mine i have 5 and I also need the top for other things. so after messing with the positioning a bit, i decided i wanted about 17% of vh for each and left room at the top. you have 7, so i would probably start around 14% vh (100/7 = ~14.2)for placing, giving each icon it's own css id, and a class to handle all the images. so for yours I would do about the same thing. to keep it square, you'll have to use vh for both the height and width. (vh stands for viewport height, so it will adjust as the view window does.)

```
#sidenav img{
    height: 14vh;
    width:  14vh;
}
#nav1{
    position: fixed;
    top:0vh;
}
#nav2{
    position: fixed;
    top:14vh;
}
#nav3{
    position: fixed;
    top:28vh;
}
#nav4{
    position: fixed;
    top:42vh;
}
#nav5{
    position: fixed;
    top:56vh;
}
#nav6{
    position: fixed;
    top:70vh;
}
#nav7{
    position: fixed;
    top:84vh;
}
```

hope that works for you. Hoping to get my first question answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this can not be done with css alone.

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  var height = document.body.clientHeight;
  var nav = document.getElementById('sidenav');
  var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  nav.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + height + 'px');
  for (var i = 0; i < image.length; ++i) {
    image[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + height / image.length + 'px');
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="sidenav">
  <div id="nav1"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav2"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav3"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav4"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav5"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav6"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
  <div id="nav7"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to try bootstrap library, it's a really good responsive library with tons of great goodies.

Here's my code using bootstrap:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Best Regards,
Khaled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media breakpoints to style your icons for special window height

```css
#sidenav{
  display: flex;
}

.nav-icon img{
  max-height: 50px;
}

@media (max-height: 700px){
  .nav-icon img{
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 500px){
  .nav-icon img{
    max-height: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 300px){
  .nav-icon img{
    max-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidenav">
    <div id="nav1" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301804.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav2" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301805.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav3" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301814.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav4" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301808.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav5" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301812.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav6" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301809.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav7" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301817.svg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

another way - using vh metrics in css to make height responsive to screen size.

```css
#sidenav{
  display: flex;
}

.nav-icon img{
  height: 15vh; /* 100vh = size of window */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidenav">
    <div id="nav1" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301804.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav2" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301805.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav3" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301814.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav4" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301808.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav5" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301812.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav6" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301809.svg" alt=""></div>
    <div id="nav7" class="nav-icon"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1301/1301817.svg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</body>
```